# simple picture over picture in html

Tags: javascript, html, image

im trying to build a website, where u click on a text, and a picture appears, when you click on this picture, the next one appears and so on. If you reach the last picture, the first one should appear if you click on it. My code is very complicated and it does not work with the last picture. I hope somebody can help me!

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showImage() {
         document.getElementById('loadingimage').style.visibility="visible";
      }
      function showImage2() {
         document.getElementById('loadingimage2').style.visibility="visible";
      }
      function showImage3() {
         document.getElementById('loadingimage3').style.visibility="visible";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="showImage()">Hier clicken</a>
    <img onclick="showImage2()" id="loadingimage" src="pic/pic1.jpg" alt="" style="visibility:hidden"></img>
    <img onclick="showImage3()" id="loadingimage2" src="pic/pic2.jpg" alt="" style="visibility:hidden"></img>
    <img onclick="showImage4()" id="loadingimage3" src="pic/pic3.jpg" alt="" style="visibility:hidden"></img>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, the `button` will be hidden after you click the first time on the button.

```js
let start = 0,
  total = 3,
  hasStarted = false;
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".image")];
const button = document.querySelector("button");

function showImage() {
  if (!hasStarted) {
    button.classList.add("hide")
    hasStarted = !hasStarted;
  }
  images.forEach(image => {
    if (image.classList.contains("show")) {
      image.classList.remove("show");
      image.classList.add("hide");
    }
  })
  document.querySelector(`.image${start}`).classList.add("show");
  ++start;
  start = start % total;
}

images.forEach(image => {
  image.addEventListener("click", showImage)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showImage()">Hier clicken</button>
<img class="image image0 hide" id="loadingimage1" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt=""></img>
<img class="image image1 hide" id="loadingimage2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt=""></img>
<img class="image image2 hide" id="loadingimage3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt=""></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is what you need:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage() {
      document.getElementById('loadingimage').style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById('loadingimage').style.position = 'absolute';
    }

    function showImage2() {
      document.getElementById('loadingimage2').style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById('loadingimage2').style.zIndex = '10';
      document.getElementById('loadingimage2').style.position = 'absolute'
    }

    function showImage3() {
      document.getElementById('loadingimage3').style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById('loadingimage3').style.zIndex = '15';
      document.getElementById('loadingimage3').style.position = 'absolute'
    }
    
    function showImage4() {
      document.getElementById('loadingimage').style.zIndex = '20';
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a onclick="showImage()">Hier clicken</a>
  <img onclick="showImage2()" id="loadingimage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x201" alt="" style="visibility:hidden">
  <img onclick="showImage3()" id="loadingimage2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x202" alt="" style="visibility:hidden">
  <img onclick="showImage4()" id="loadingimage3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x203" alt="" style="visibility:hidden">
</body>
```